# Verification of solution for the given floor sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, solution-verification, contest-math

> Brute force me if you can$$\left\lfloor\sqrt[1]{2\choose 1}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\sqrt[2]{4\choose 2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\sqrt[3]{6\choose 3}\right\rfloor+\cdots +\left\lfloor\sqrt[1010]{2020\choose 1010}\right\rfloor$$
> Find the sum

I found this question on a math olympiad discord server. No solution was given there so I wanted to verify the solution I and my friend came up with:

***My Approach:***

***PART I***

Let us generalize
$${2n\choose n}^\frac{1}{n}=\Big(\dfrac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{n!\cdot n!}\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$$

This is equal to:
$$\Big(\dfrac{2^n\cdot n!(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1}{n!n!}\Big)^\frac{1}{n}=\Big(\dfrac{2^n\cdot (2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1}{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Which is equal to:
$$\Big(2^n\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n-1}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n-2}\Big)\cdots \Big(2-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{1}\Big)\Big)^\frac{1}{n}=2\Big(\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n-1}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n-2}\Big)\cdots \Big(2-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{1}\Big)\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Lets say the given product is $P$

Now $2\Big(\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)^n\Big)^\frac{1}{n}>P>2\Big(\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{1}\Big)^n\Big)^\frac{1}{n}$

This gives $2\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)>P>2$

***PART II***

By observation, we get that $P<3$ when $n<5$

Claim:${2n\choose n} >3^n\forall\ n\geq 5$

Proof:${10\choose 5}=252>3^5=243$

Now suppose the given claim is true

We know that $${2n\choose n}=2^n\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n-1}\Big)\cdots \Big(2-\dfrac{1}{2}\Big)\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{1}\Big)$$

Therefore ${2(n+1)\choose (n+1)}=2\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\Big){2n\choose n}$

Thus ${2(n+1)\choose (n+1)}>3^n\times 2\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\Big)>3^n\times 3$

This means that $2\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\Big)>3$

Solving this would give that this inequality is valid for $n>1$, thus also valid for $n\geq5$.

Thus our claim is true which means that $4>2\Big(2-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)>{2n\choose n}^\frac{1}{n}>3$ when $n\geq 5$

This means that $3>P>2$ when $n<5$ and $4>P>3$ when $n\geq 5$, therefore $\lfloor{P}\rfloor=2$ for $n<5$ and $\lfloor{P}\rfloor=3$ for $n\geq 5$.

Thus the value of our sum is $2\times 4+3\times 1006=3026$

Please check my solution for any mistakes. Also please recommend any alternative solutions if possible.

***THANKS***

Comment: yes, sorry I fogot to add it.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+1010+%28floor%28%282n+choose+n%29%5E%281%2Fn%29%29%29), the sum is indeed $3026$. Good job.

Comment: @thanks for helping. Do you have any alternative solutions in mind? Also please can you edit the question? I don't know how to put floor function.

Comment: You need `\lfloor \rfloor`. I think your solution is pretty clean.